# Parsing large text file using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a large text file (60Mb) that looks like the following:

```
:VPN ()
:add_adtr_rule (true)
:additional_products ()
:addr_type_indication (IPv4)
:certificates ()
:color (black)
:comments ()
:connectra (false)
:connectra_settings ()
:cp_products_installed (false)
:data_source (not-installed)
:data_source_settings ()
:edges ()
:enforce_gtp_rate_limit (false)
:firewall (not-installed)
:floodgate (not-installed)
:gtp_rate_limit (2048)
:interfaces ()
:ipaddr (10.19.45.18)
```

for every instance in which :add_adtr_rule is true, there are thousands of ':add_adtr_rule (false)' entries, I need the value of the ipaddr - so in this instance I would need the 10.19.45.18. How can I use a regex to extract this information.

I have tried the following code, that returns an empty list:

```
import re

with open("objects_5_0_C-Mod.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

ip=re.findall(r':add_adtr_rule [\(]true[\)]\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+:ipaddr\s+[\(](.*)[\)]', text)
print(ip)
```

Comment: Assuming that the file consists of repeated blocks like the above, and given that I am not a regex expert, I would have started by writing a generator yielding one block at a time.  This would be generically useful for querying the file.  I would have then tested for the 'true' and extracted or ignored depending.  But siam's regex looks good for a one-off job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following *regex* should do it :

```
(?s)(?:add_adtr_rule\s\(true\)).*?:ipaddr\s\((.*?)\)
```

*see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/c22Kxm/2)***

**python** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/CoLNev) )

```
import re

s = """:VPN () :add_adtr_rule (true) :additional_products () :addr_type_indication (IPv4) :certificates () :color (black) :comments () :connectra (false) :connectra_settings () :cp_products_installed (false) :data_source (not-installed) :data_source_settings () :edges () :enforce_gtp_rate_limit (false) :firewall (not-installed) :floodgate (not-installed) :gtp_rate_limit (2048) :interfaces () :ipaddr (10.19.45.18)"""
r = r"(?s)(?:add_adtr_rule\s\(true\)).*?:ipaddr\s\((.*?)\)"
ip = re.findall(r, s)
print (ip)
```

Comment: Nice.  By working the your regex with the manual, https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax, I learned some new features.

Comment: @Clyde Glad it worked! BTW, an accept would be much appreciated tho :-)

Comment: @Siam - What do you mean by accept? Sorry I'm fairly new to this site.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add anchors to speed up things. Consider the following example with `MULTILINE` and `VERBOSE` turned on:

```
^:add_adtr_rule\ \(true\)   # start of line, followed by :add_ ...
[\s\S]+?                    # everything else afterwards, lazily          
^:ipaddr\ \((?P<ip>[^)]+)\) # start of line, ip and group "ip" between ()
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xZvE1E/2).

---

With your given code this comes down to:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
        ^:add_adtr_rule\ \(true\)
        [\s\S]+?
        ^:ipaddr\ \((?P<ip>[^)]+)\) 
        ''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

with open("objects_5_0_C-Mod.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

ips = [match.group('ip') for match in rx.finditer(text)]
print(ips)
```